# Como ejecutar el código desde el terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Quería saber si podéis ayudarme con esta duda que tengo. Tengo un código de un cliente y de un servidor, y quiero ejecutar ese código desde el terminal.

```
python3 TFTP_ClienteUDP.py
```

Número de argumentos incorrectos, compruebe que tenga este formato:

`TFTP_CLIENTE-S<SERVER>-P<PORT>`

Y es que no sé que es lo que tengo que poner detrás de `python3 TFTP_ClienteUDP.py` . Gracias

Comment: Ese mensaje es generado por el programa `TFTP_ClienteUDP.py`. Debes leer su código para ver de qué forma utiliza la lista `sys.argv[]`. El elemento 0 de esa lista será el nombre del script, y los restantes elementos (1,2, 3...) las palabras que pongas detrás del script, en la línea de comandos. Así, si ves que el código intenta usar `sys.argv[1]` como IP a la que conectarse, sabrás que el primer argumento a darle por línea de comandos sería la IP del servidor, etc.

Comment: Dado que estás ante un cliente TFTP `S` y `P` supongo que podrían ser servidor (ip) y puerto respectivamente, es decir deberías llamarlo algo así `TFTP_ClienteUDP.py -tftp.myserver.com -69` / `TFTP_ClienteUDP.py -192.168.1.100 -69` obviamente la ip y puerto deben ser las de tu servidor TFTP. Obviamente estoy presuponiendo cosas, para saberlo con certeza es necesario conocer el contenido del script  como comenta abulafia o al menos la parte en la que se parsean los argumentos. También podría ser `Server` y  `Put`, para designar que se quiere enviar o mil cosas más...

Comment: Ah, tras la edición a la pregunta puede verse que (aparentemente) espera la cadena `-S` seguida del nombre (o IP) del servidor, y la cadena `-P` seguida del puerto. Un ejemplo de llamada entonces podría ser `python TFTP_ClienteUDP.py -S 192.168.1.5 -P 69`. No está claro si la IP y puerto deben ir "pegadas" a las opciones `-S` y `-P`, o si deben ir separadas con un espacio que es más habitual. Haz pruebas, y examina el código.